# GetWindowText() in Win32 C++ is not working

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi

following code is not working .i am trying to get text from edit control but it does not work.m tired by trying all possible codes looking documentation on msdn etc...

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch(LOWORD(wParam)){
    case 1:
        ::MessageBox(hwnd,"button clicked","message",MB_OK);
        break;
    case 2: 
        TCHAR t[20]; // 
            GetWindowText(text_box,t,19);// this is not working????????????????
        ::MessageBox(hwnd,t,t,MB_OK);
        cout<<t;



        break;
```

for refrence below is the complete code :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

const char g_szClassName[] = "myWindowClass";

// Step 4: the Window Procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HWND text_field, button , text_box;
    char text_saved[20];

    switch(msg)

    {   case WM_CREATE:
         text_field = CreateWindow("STATIC",
            "Hello World",
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
            20,20, 90,25,
            hwnd,
            NULL,NULL,NULL);
        button = CreateWindow("BUTTON",
            "push button",
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
            20,50, 100,20,
            hwnd,
            (HMENU)1,NULL,NULL  
            )  ;
        text_box = CreateWindow("EDIT",
            " ",
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
            20,80, 200,25,
            hwnd,
            NULL,NULL,NULL
            );
        CreateWindow("BUTTON",
            "Save",
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
            20,120, 100,20,
            hwnd,
            (HMENU)2,NULL,NULL  
            );





    break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(LOWORD(wParam)){
        case 1:
            ::MessageBox(hwnd,"button clicked","message",MB_OK);
            break;
        case 2: 
            TCHAR t[20];
                GetWindowText(text_box,t,19);
            ::MessageBox(hwnd,t,t,MB_OK);
            cout<<t;



            break;



    }
    break;

        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    //Step 1: Registering the Window Class
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    // Step 2: Creating the Window
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        g_szClassName,
        "The title of my window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 500,500,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if(hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!", "Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    // Step 3: The Message Loop
    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
 }
```

Comment: @Jonathan Potter i tried making variables global but no use :( it still gives blank msgbox

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a working reworked version of your code, replacing the local variable `text_box` (which doesn't retain information from one call to the next) with a numerical control id and use of `GetDlgItem`, changing from ANSI to Unicode text, and fixing some other stuff, while mainly keeping the formatting:

```
#undef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>

#include<iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

namespace g {
    const auto class_name = L"myWindowClass";

    const auto push_button_id   = 1;
    const auto save_button_id   = 2;
    const auto edit_field_id    = 3;

    const auto h_instance = ::GetModuleHandle( nullptr );
}  // namespace g


// Step 4: the Window Procedure

void create_controls( const HWND hwnd )
{
    CreateWindow( L"STATIC",
                            L"Hello World",
                            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
                            20,20, 90,25,
                            hwnd,
                            nullptr, g::h_instance, nullptr );
    CreateWindow( L"BUTTON",
                            L"push button",
                            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
                            20,50, 100,20,
                            hwnd,
                            (HMENU) g::push_button_id, g::h_instance, nullptr
                            )  ;
    CreateWindow( L"EDIT",
                            L"",
                            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
                            20,80, 200,25,
                            hwnd,
                            (HMENU) g::edit_field_id, g::h_instance, nullptr
                            );
    CreateWindow( L"BUTTON",
                            L"Save",
                            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
                            20,120, 100,20,
                            hwnd,
                            (HMENU) g::save_button_id, g::h_instance, nullptr
                            );
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        create_controls( hwnd );
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(LOWORD(wParam)) {
        case 1:
            ::MessageBox( hwnd, L"button clicked", L"message", MB_SETFOREGROUND );
            break;
        case 2:
            const HWND text_box = GetDlgItem( hwnd, g::edit_field_id );
            const int n = GetWindowTextLength( text_box );
            wstring text( n + 1, L'#' );
            if( n > 0 )
            {
                GetWindowText( text_box, &text[0], text.length() );
            }
            text.resize( n );
            ::MessageBox(hwnd, text.c_str(), L"The text:", MB_SETFOREGROUND );
            break;
        }
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    //Step 1: Registering the Window Class
    WNDCLASSEX wc = { sizeof( WNDCLASSEX ) };

    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = g::h_instance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH>(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = nullptr;
    wc.lpszClassName = g::class_name;
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(nullptr, L"Window Registration Failed!", L"Error!",
                   MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_SETFOREGROUND );
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    // Step 2: Creating the Window
    const HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
               WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
               g::class_name,
               L"The title of my window",
               WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
               CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 500,500,
               nullptr, nullptr, g::h_instance, nullptr);

    if(hwnd == nullptr)
    {
        MessageBox(nullptr, L"Window Creation Failed!", L"Error!",
                   MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_SETFOREGROUND);
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);   // Note: any other value is replaced.
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);                 // Not strictly necessary.

    // Step 3: The Message Loop
    MSG Msg;
    int get_message_result;
    while( (get_message_result = GetMessage(&Msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) > 0 )
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return (get_message_result < 0? E_FAIL : Msg.wParam);
}
```

Comment: thankyou for the beautiful code but when i run it using gcc it throws a bunch of errors

Comment: Probably those are warnings, not errors, since I only compiled this code with g++. Because of your comment I now checked that it also compiles with Visual C++. Neither compiler produces any errors or warnings here, with `/W4` for Visual C++ and `-pedantic-errors` for g++.

Comment: with g++ even with -pedantic-errors it shows no. of errors relating to that namepace g . in simple words compiler is unable to recognize variables defined inside namespace g

Comment: i am sorry if i am making silly mistakes this is my first time doing gui after console applications.

Comment: hey this worked :) a million thanks for giving a correct solution. i tried this with dev c++ compiler n it works just perfect. but when i truy to compile using command line like this :`code` g++ -o test.exe test.cpp `code` it gives error can u tell why?

Comment: The Unicode versions of the Windows API have a `W` suffix, e.g. `CreateWindowExW`. If you call `CreateWindowEx`, the correct string type is `TCHAR`. You'll have to change either the string data type, or the function signature.

Comment: @user3521918: Oh sorry, you have to specify C++11 standard or later to compile the `auto` declarations. With g++ use `-std=c++11`. I have that as default, didn't think of it, mea culpa! That is, the code is good by current standards. But many distributions of g++ default to older C++03 standard.

Comment: @Cheers and hth yeah thanks again :) wish me luck to my GUI programming learning.some silly mistakes and it took damn 8 hrs to get it correct and running...

Comment: @llnspectable cheers answer  is perfect n his code is very neat anyone can grap it in one go. i respect your efforts too . y not instead of stamping on each other create a better ecosystem for upcoming programmers and learners

Comment: Since readers may get the entirely wrong impression from IInspectable's recommendations, Microsoft's `TCHAR` (and other `T` ) macros were once a Windows 9x compatibility feature. They were obsolete already in the year 2000, with the introduction of Layer for Unicode (for those who wished to target Windows 9x). With `UNICODE` defined, as it is in this code and in all quality non-legacy modern Windows code, `TCHAR` resolves to `wchar_t`.

Comment: @llnspectable maybe you are right then you should provide here a code trhat is proper  according to you. he atleast took time to read my complete code and rewrite it from scratch. i am willing to see your code too post it here as a styling guidline maybe

Comment: @user3521918: You should heed the guy's advice about the control id's. It doesn't matter in this program, but it can matter in a dialog. However, ignore the rest. ;-)

Comment: @IInspectable: the OP was "trying to get text from edit control". This answer says it's "replacing the local variable with a numerical control id". It's possible that the reason the OP understood that as a solution, was the [earlier discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29066769/getwindowtext-in-win32-c-is-not-working/29067698?noredirect=1#comment46369554_29066830), but I think that as nearly every other of your claims, also this one about not understanding the answer is nonsense, again. Still I'm clarifying that. Not fixing id's or other problems of the OP's code (no end to that).

Answer (score 5):

You've defined `text_box` (and the other variables) as local to the `WndProc` function, meaning their values are lost every time that function is called to process a message. You need to move them outside of the function scope (or make them `static`) if you want to preserve their values from one message to the next.

Comment: Since this is Windows programming a more practical solution is to use a different way to identify a control, such as via a numerical control id. The OP might find it worthwhile to check out e.g. `GetDlgItem`. And yes, it can be used with any window, not just dialogs.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf it's probably more important that the OP learns about variable lifetime and scope at this point in their programming career :)

Comment: @jonathan i tried it making global again no luck :(. btw thanks for helping